# Ubuntu 14.04 Lts wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

My Wifi is connected perfectly with a good signal strength, but sometimes it just won't get connected or the connection is very slow and not working properly. The connection on Windows 8 on the same notebook (Lenovo Flex 2-14) was working smoothly.

After the bootup it works fine, but after a few minutes the problem arrives. The wifi adapter doesn't react anymore and I'm not able to (re/dis)connect with the router anymore. I have to restart to get it working again...

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 26 Mar 2015 10:56 CET +0100

Booted last: 26 Mar 2015 10:53 CET +0100

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3810]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:0447 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8723be              85054  0 
btcoexist              50304  1 rtl8723be
rtl8723_common         23361  1 rtl8723be
rtl_pci                26690  1 rtl8723be
rtlwifi                64255  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723be
mac80211              652718  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8723be
cfg80211              494362  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          200204  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               104112  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
wmi                    19193  0 
ideapad_laptop         18278  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.26  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1036 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:665425 (665.4 KB)  TX bytes:140032 (140.0 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"WichtelLAN"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'WichtelLAN' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:8   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [WichtelLAN] --------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8723be
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           65 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    foo:         Infra, <MAC 'foo' [AC3]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 80 WPA WPA2
    UPC2038313:      Infra, <MAC 'UPC2038313' [AC8]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 74 WPA WPA2
    foo:         Infra, <MAC 'foo' [AC2]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
    1ADialup:        Infra, <MAC '1ADialup' [AN4]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64 WPA WPA2
    WichtelLAN_EXT:  Infra, <MAC 'WichtelLAN_EXT' [AC4]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64 WPA2
    UPC2757394:      Infra, <MAC 'UPC2757394' [AC6]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA WPA2
    BIBULE:          Infra, <MAC 'BIBULE' [AC7]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54 WPA
    *WichtelLAN:     Infra, <MAC 'WichtelLAN' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 80 WPA2
    UPC0397341:      Infra, <MAC 'UPC0397341' [AC12]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67 WPA WPA2
    UPC0055582:      Infra, <MAC 'UPC0055582' [AN10]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    UPC2126316:      Infra, <MAC 'UPC2126316' [AC5]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA WPA2
    Haiti3D:         Infra, <MAC 'Haiti3D' [AC10]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 47 WPA WPA2
    ThomsonE579A7:   Infra, <MAC 'ThomsonE579A7' [AN13]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 54

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.26
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.138

    DNS:             10.0.0.138

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WLAN am See]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WLAN am See | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WLAN am See | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WichtelLAN]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WichtelLAN | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WichtelLAN | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto
```

Comment: Can you post the results of the script- wireless-info.txt rather than the script itself- wireless_script

Comment: Sry, I edited the first comment and posted the results in two parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by doing this

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot and see if it works

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks for the solution, it worked. Can you tell me how exactly you found out what to do?

Comment: It is a fix that has been around for a while